# How to document Queues using RabbitMq Admin UI

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-management

We have a requirement where rabbitMq administrator need to have informations regardings Queues that have been defined and are used.

They need informations like fonctional(business) description of the Queue and/or the structure of the message that will be send in the queue.

Of course we can provide thoses informations as an external documentation (ex: Wiki).

But I would like to have code as doc feature an be able declare all thoses informations whithin the queues definitions (definition.json). And then use the rabbitMq Admin UI to display thoses informations.

I wasn't able to found any doc related to this need, is it something feasible with any existing RabbitMQ version or plugin ?

Or m I doomed to maintain external wiki documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any arbitrary arguments to the queue definition:

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable("so59685252")
            .withArgument("about", "this is the information about this queue")
            .withArgument("more", "more info")
            .build();
}
```

and

[image]

Comment: This is what i was looking for, thank you very much !